# How can I update my site without hard coding?

Tags: website

I have a website for a company purposes and it's selling the car plate and it need to be updated every now and then. But I do not wish to card code them as it takes a long time to update them. Are they any other ways to update the site?

Answer (score 3):

Use a CMS (=Content Management System). You can easily update the site contents without hard coding anything.

A good starting point is www.opensourcecms.com.